# Regex to find regular sentence vs title

Tags: regex

First post! I'm usually very good with Regex, but struggle with negative and positive lookahead and lookbehind. It just doesn't click with my head.

I'm trying to pull titles from text. They are in title case. I need to pull the title and leave behind the description.

Examples:

```
This is the Title This is the sentence and it's longer...
Title Course I Find blue, red, green...
```

There is usually no punctuation between title and description.

The title consistently comes after this pattern:

`([A-Z]{2,4}[&]?\s[\d]{3})`

for example: `MATH 123 This Title is Awesome This course brings together...`

Thoughts?

Comment: MATH 123 This Title is Awesome This course brings together...--- What is the title you are trying to pull here ?

Comment: you need to specify more clear examples and desire outputs!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: See [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow/51145#:~:text=6%20Answers&text=If%20you%20post%20code%20or,format%20and%20syntax%20highlight%20it.&text=Or%20for%20block%20code%2C%20you,%22it%20works!%22) about formatting code in SO questions, answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MATH 123 is the ID and the pattern is consistent you'd still need some form of delimiter between your Title and Description or at least a pattern to match. In the below example I've assumed

```
ID: MATH 513, 
Title: This Title is Awesome
Description: This course brings together
```

With a simple hyphen delimiter you can match ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, I'd recommend tuning the regex to remove .* where possible.

```
(?<id>[A-Z]{2,4}[&]?\s[\d]{3}) (?<Title>.*?) - (?<Description>.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should match the title as long as the description always starts with `Capitalized uncapitalized`:

```
^.+(?=[A-Z][a-z]+\s[a-z])
```

Course numbers like `MATH 123` will also be captured in this, so you'll need to extract them separately or remove them beforehand.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TYDKeF/2)